# Proving whether a set of vectors is in the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Say $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $S$ is the set of all vectors of the form $s_1+s_2$, where $s_1\in S_1$ and $s_2 \in S_2$. So therefore $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well.

Is this is accurate statement? My initial assumption is yes. Have to check whether $S$ is closed under addition, scalar multiplication. How would I go on to prove it?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The checklist to check that $S$ is a subspace is:

1) Is $0 \in S$?

2) If $(s_1+s_2) \in S$ and $(t_1 + t_2) \in S$ then is $(s_1+s_2)+(t_1+t_2) \in S$?

3) If $(s_1 + s_2) \in S$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then is $\lambda(s_1 + s_2) \in S$?

$S$ will be a subspace if and only if you can answer yes to all three.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$(s_1+s_2)+(s_1'+s_2')=(s_1+s_1')+(s_2+s_2')$$

$$k(s_1+s_2)=ks_1+ks_2\;,\;\;ks_i\in\ldots?$$